# Proper way to send the same data in every AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create a base AJAX setting to send the username and password configuration along with every AJAX call. I am not discussing if this is the right method to do, this is a must for my project and there are other security configurations in place, so...

What I thought was using the `jQuery.ajaxSetup(options)` options object creating the data, but when I define additional data for my POST functions, that **data** object would be overriden.

P.S. I believe there is no need to show what I did or where is my code, etc. I hope the question itself is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrong! Setting default data in `ajaxSetup` and then adding more data in the ajax call itself does not overwrite the default data.

It works like this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        username: "Bill Gates",
        password: "Nerdman"
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "script.php",
    data: {
        id: 4,
        company: "Microsoft"
    }
});
```

The final URL will be `script.php?username=Bill+Gates&password=Nerdman&id=4&company=Microsoft"`, making the final data object that is sent in the request

```
data: {
    username: "Bill Gates",
    password: "Nerdman",
    id: 4,
    company: "Microsoft"
}
```

so all the data ***will be sent***, and it's the same with POST requests, all data will be added.

Here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xnnruLen/), inspect the URL in the console, and all the added data is there, as the data object is cumulative, and added to for each call to `$.ajaxSetup`, it's never overwritten.

jQuery does however also offer prefilters that are intended for this kind of data manipulation, where one can add data to all the ajax calls right before they are sent, by just writing the code once, instead of using `beforeSend` on every call

```
var settings = {
    username: "Bill Gates",
    password: "Nerdman"
}

$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, settings))
});

// later

$.ajax({
    url  : 'something.php',
    data : {"more" : "data"} // the above settings will be added as well
});
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. A complete answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of **[`beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** and **[`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)** to add extra details with common details to your `request` as below:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'someurl',
        type:'POST',
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
              settings.data = $.extend(
                      settings.data, { 
                      //your new data here 
                      }
              );
              return true;
        }
        //other related things
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to add additional information to basic config:

```
var defaultConfig = {username: "User", password: "Insecure Plain Password"};

$.ajax({
    url: 'launchMission.php',
    data: $.extend(defaultConfig, {missionId: 15, destroyUniverse: true})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly calling the ajax method, create a base javascript function and have all pages extend this base method using `$.extend()` . Create a sendAjax method in this base file and take the options as parameters. Then add in your configuration to this data and make the ajax call. In every class that needs to make ajax calls, call the `sendAjax()` method and pass in the data and options

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the answer by reading [jQuery.ajaxSetup's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/):

> For that reason we strongly recommend against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the call or define a simple plugin to do so.

Basically, what they recommend is creating your own wrapper around `jQuery.ajax` (it can be in the form of a jQuery plugin or not).